# Laravel 5 view composer service provider, exclude prefix from wildcard

Tags: php, laravel-5

Following the [view composer documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers) I've created a class ComposerServiceProvider and a ViewComposer for my basic views. I want to use another view composer for the administration area of my site called AdminComposer. These are my class headers:

```
(namespace App\Http\Composers)

class ViewComposer
class AdminComposer extends ViewComposer
```

This is my Composer Service provider:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('admin/*', 'App\Http\Composers\AdminComposer');
        View::composer('*', 'App\Http\Composers\ViewComposer');
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

In the method boot() of my composer service provider I want to assign the ViewComposer to all my views, except for the ones with the prefix "admin", which should use AdminComposer.

In the current setting however, both view composers are used, as path "admin/*" adheres to path "*/" as well. Is there a way I can exclude the admin prefix from the wildcard path, without having to individually declare all paths that will use ViewComposer instead?

Comment: For what do you need the view composers? It might be enough to just attach it to the layout view of the two areas.

Comment: It contains all kinds of standard input, data, variables and the likes. I used to have these in Laravel 4, where I just made a custom view method, which doesn't work nicely anymore in L5. I set default page titles, add a list of stylesheets and scripts to load, load some user settings, etc. The AdminComposer only overrides a tiny part of the ViewComposer.

Comment: Do you think attaching them to the layout views would work?

Comment: Not sure. If that involves doing anything using "$this->layout" in a controller, then no, as I'm not using that in my application.

Comment: No definitely not. I assume you are using `@extends('something')` in your views? That something would be your "layout" view.

Comment: Yes I'm using that. The things I'm doing in my view composer do seem to be a too complicated to do in a view, and I'd rather not mess around in my base controller. I liked having all my basic template data code somewhere I can't see it normally.

Comment: Of course. I'm just suggesting to use `View::composer('admin_layout', ...)`  and `View::composer('normal_layout', ...)` instead of wildcards

Comment: Settings the first parameter of the composer methods inside boot() to "layouts.admin" and "layouts.master" (respectively) did the trick. Thank you! Feel free to add this as an answer below for some rep :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's probably enough to only attach the view composers to your two layout files. This way you not only resolve the conflict between normal and admin views but also the composer runs just once per request and not twice or more (for the view and the layout view and possibly more views)

```
View::composer('layouts.admin', 'App\Http\Composers\AdminComposer');
View::composer('layouts.master', 'App\Http\Composers\ViewComposer');
```